# NavBar Display Different Chrome/Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am facing a strange problem where the a navbar I have created is displaying differently in Chrome than Firefox. Here is a screenshot of each. Firefox is displaying it correctly:

[image: Firefox Navbar]

While the background colors are getting lost in Chrome:

[image: Chrome Navbar]

I have created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nick_B/5axap/13/), but the problem is not apparent when viewed on the jsfiddle site using Chrome. In the live Chrome browser, the `body` declaration over-rides the definition for the navbar, even though `z-index` is used.. Any ideas on how to solve this strange issue? Im using an old version of Chrome right now (21.0.1180.90), trying to insure backwards compatibility. Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine tested in "live Chrome browser" 21.0.1180.89 (couldn't find the 21.0.1180.90) on OS X 10.8.2.

And I think you are missing the point of `z-index`:

> For a positioned box, the 'z-index' property specifies:
>
> - The stack level of the box in the current stacking context.
> - Whether the box establishes a stacking context.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index

`z-index` is not used to override any other css declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You're code is working in Chrome version 24 , Firefox and Internet Explorer 10 . Maybe the problem is only in that version of Chrome or you override it somewhere else.